# Jakarta JSTL Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jstl

I am developing a web application in IntelliJ with Java/Jakarta, Maven and Tomcat 10.
Therefore I want to use the JSTL Tags, but can't get them to work.

Through Maven I've added org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:2.0.0. to my project. I've also added the jar file in the Tomcat/lib folder.

In the jsp file I've added:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

To solve the problem "The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application" I've added the dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
 <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I'm having the following problem:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag
```

Thank you for your time :)!

Answer (score 1):

The `jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar` and `jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar` files don't go in the `Tomcat/lib` folder.

They should be put into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in the `.war` file.